# What is the cumulative distribution function for the ratio of the shorter and longer lengths?

Tags: probability

I pick a uniformly random point on a stick of length 1 and sunder the stick there. What is the cumulative distribution function for the ratio of the shorter and longer lengths?

If I let

$S \rightarrow $ shorter length 
$L \rightarrow $ longer length 
$R \rightarrow $ ratio of shorter and longer lengths ($\frac{S}{L}$)

then

$P(R \le k) = P(\frac{S}{L} \le k) = P(S \le Lk) = P(S \le k(1 - S)) = P(S \le k - kS) = P(S \le \frac{k}{k + 1})$

However, I am not sure where to go from here... any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** First find the cumulative distribution function or density function of $S$. The rest is as in your approach.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**
$$\Pr\left\lbrace S>c\right\rbrace=\Pr\left\lbrace \lvert X-0.5\rvert<\max\left(0.5 -c,0\right)\right\rbrace,$$ where $X$ is uniformly chosen from $\left[0,1\right]$.

Answer (score 1):

As $X$ increases from $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ to $1$, $R = \begin{cases} \frac{X}{1-X}, &0 \leq X \leq \frac{1}{2},\\
&\\
\frac{1-X}{X}, &\frac{1}{2} < X \leq 1,\end{cases}$ increases from $0$
at $X=0$,
attains a maximum value of $1$ when $X = \frac{1}{2}$, and then decreases
to $0$ when $X = 1$.

Thus, for $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$, 
$$
1-F_R(\alpha) = P\{R > \alpha\} 
= P\left\{\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha} < X < \frac{1}{1+\alpha}\right\}
= F_X\left(\frac{1}{1+\alpha}\right) - F_X\left(\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\right).
$$

Can you take it from there?